# flask json to geojson incorrect format when using jsonify

Tags: python, json, rest, flask-restful

Trying to return geosjon using flask. I don't get the correct format when I use jsonify, when I use json.dumps I get the correct format, can someone explain why?

```
from flask import jsonify
import sqlite3


@app.route("/population")
def status():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('population.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row 
    db = conn.cursor()
    rows = db.execute('''
    SELECT * from info
    ''').fetchall()

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    json_format = [dict(ix) for ix in rows]
    geojson = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [data["LONG"], data["LAT"]],
            },
            "properties" : {

                'name':data['NAME'],
                'population':data['POPULATION']
            }
        } for data in json_format]
    }

    return jsonify(geojson)
```

**expected output**

{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-87.661557, 41.893748]}, "properties": {"name": "WASHINGTON", "POPULATION": 1232132}}]}

**Actual**
{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-87.661557,41.893748],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"name":"","WASHINGTON":1232132},"type":"Feature"}],"type":"FeatureCollection"}

Comment: I don't see any error in your "actual" output. What is it that does not work?

Comment: shouldn't featurescollectoin be first and not last for geojson?

Comment: Nope, that is not a requirement. The object/dictionary structure with `{}` is unordered.

Comment:  is there a way to output as my expected besides using jsondumps

Comment: Not sure there is, possibly it gets ordered by alphabet. The real question to ask is why would you bother?

Comment: when I make a get request from "/population" I expect it to be in geojson. what you're saying is the order doesn't matter and it will be in the correct format?

Comment: I’m saying your geojson looks correct.